# Tools for phreaking?

Tags: mobile, phone

Does Kali Linux offers tools and programs for testing security of telephones? If not, where can I get tools for this? Literally a pentest suite but focused on telephone networks, SIM cards, mobile phones etc?

Comment: Have you looked for any information about the Kali tool set? It is well documented.

Comment: You should get a modem with telephony features and an AT command set...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since phreaking is broad, i will try to cover the important points.

### General knowledge

Before trying to phreak out some of your devices i strongly recommend to study those fields:

- Some examples of typical ISP (internet service provider) network Architecture

[image: enterprise]

[image: home]

- Some examples of typical MNO (Mobile network operator) network Architecture

[image: mno]

- Analog(copper) lines and recent telco technologies

[image: analog]

Lot of service provider companies are maintaining both MNO **and** ISP network infrastructure. Learning how those two distinct networks communicate to each other will help you much more than stating some Phreaker softs. for instance start by reading those two pages:

[IMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Multimedia_Subsystem)

[UMTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMTS)

> "Why are you talking about MNO or ISP infrastructure?"
> you might say.

Well, regarding phreaking, knowing how those infra works should answer half your question. Telling you indirectly what you can do with a computer and what you cannot.

### Answer

You can play with some metasploit SIP modules, create AP or setup PPP dialup. It can be instructive and teach you some basics, like the **Mo**dulation and **Dem**odulation (Yes, this is how the Modem word was born.) Or the difference between copper and radio networks, and intrinsically learn about the interoperability between them. Of course the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) should have no secret for you.

If you truly want assess phone security in depth, you need more than a linux distro. You need **hardware.**

- 3 Android phones with 3 sims would be good. (caller, callee(victim), attacker)
- adding a Copper network phone or two to your lab would be better.
- Build/buy some [phreaking box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phreaking_boxes) would be the best. (**be very careful on this point!** owning a box, whatever the color, can be illegal in your country jurisdiction, you might need some special authorization to have one, please inquire, don't take it lightly.)

Last important point: dont try to spoof or create a MNO's LTE/3G/4G antenna.

Have fun.